# jQuery - Table with Button on every row, how to toggleClass on button clicked?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a dataTable and in each row I have a button which when clicked it shows another row. I want to attach a class to the button clicked. I tried just adding a `$('#detailMenuDropdown').addClass('rotate');` but it was only changing the first button.

My research pointed me to using a mix of this and find but it's still not working.

```
  $("#complexProcessTable tbody").on('click', '#detailMenuDropdown', function () {
    let table = $("#complexProcessTable").DataTable();
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    let row = table.row(tr);


    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
        $(this).find('#detailMenuDropdown').removeClass('rotate');
    }
    else {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        $(this).find('#detailMenuDropdown').addClass('rotate');
    }
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` need to be unique per element so convert button `id="detailMenuDropdown"` to `class="detailMenuDropdown"` and then change code like below:

```
$("#complexProcessTable tbody").on('click', '.detailMenuDropdown', function () {
   //----------------------------------------^use . instead of #
    $(this).toggleClass('rotate'); //toggle class on button
    let table = $("#complexProcessTable").DataTable();
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    let row = table.row(tr);


    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
})
```